# How to set mongod.conf bindIp with multiple ip address (in mongodb 4.4)

Tags: mongodb

I've tried this syntax,

bindIp = [127.0.0.1, 192.168.184.155, 96.88.169.145]

But it's not working at all saying unable to start mongod service. I'm using centos 7 and everything else works except when I try to use multiple IPs in the MongoDB config, then mongod service fails to start.

Answer (score 2):

The [config file](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/index.html) is a YAML format, so config valures are given as `key: value` (not `key = value`)

Try these ones:

```
bindIp: [127.0.0.1, 192.168.184.155, 96.88.169.145]
```

or

```
bindIp: 
  - 127.0.0.1
  - 192.168.184.155
  - 96.88.169.145
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this ,

bindIp = 127.0.0.1, 192.168.184.155, 96.88.169.145

Then restart Mongod

```
sudo service mongod restart
```